# libgdx rendering tiledmap at a certain X coordinate of camera

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to implement infinite scrolling in this Android game. To test this I'm just creating two tiledMaps with the same .tmx file, and then rendering them one after the other with respect to their x-values.

The problem is that I can't get this setView to work:

```
TiledMap tiledMap2 = new TiledMap();
TmxMapLoader loader2 = new TmxMapLoader();
tiledMap2 = loader2.load("data/map1.tmx");


OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer tileRenderer2 = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap2);
tileRenderer2.setView(camera.combined, 512, 0, 512, 512);
tileRenderer2.render();
```

Now I get this exact chunk of code to work earlier if I just use

```
tileRenderer2.setView(camera);
```

instead of

```
tileRenderer2.setView(camera.combined, 512, 0, 512, 512);
```

Is my problem one with the first argument of setView()?

Answer (score 1):

just change the position of your camera and you are done. `camera.position.x = ...` and `camera.position.y = ...`
With setView you just define the Camera that does define the View. It does not define the position of the camera. It just the view-bounds for the internal optimized rendering.

```
@Override
public void setView(OrthographicCamera camera) {
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    float width = camera.viewportWidth * camera.zoom;
    float height = camera.viewportHeight * camera.zoom;
    viewBounds.set(camera.position.x - width / 2, camera.position.y - height / 2, width, height);
}
```

Thats used inside of the RenderTileLayer method for getting the first and last tiles that are visible :

```
final int col1 = Math.max(0, (int) (viewBounds.x / layerTileWidth));
final int col2 = Math.min(layerWidth, (int) ((viewBounds.x + viewBounds.width + layerTileWidth) / layerTileWidth));

final int row1 = Math.max(0, (int) (viewBounds.y / layerTileHeight));
final int row2 = Math.min(layerHeight, (int) ((viewBounds.y + viewBounds.height + layerTileHeight) / layerTileHeight)); 
//here does follow the rendering
```

Everthing from the sourcecode from libGDX

Comment: Hmm see I am using camera.position.x =... in my code. I'm using that to do the scrolling. My question was more for, how do I render the tile maps one after the other? Say I have 2 tilemaps that look like [111] and [222]. How do I render them at the same time one after the other so they appear like [111][222], because once one goes off the screen, I'll then 'leap frog' it over the other, so it would then look like [222][111], and so on so it's an 'infinite' scrolling.

Comment: Here's an example I made a while back for doing something like what you are describing: https://github.com/MobiDevelop/libgdx/blob/example/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/examples/RunnerExample.java

Comment: @nEx.Software Thanks a bunch for showing me that. I just started using libgdx 3 days ago hehe. I'm having serious trouble figuring out how this works. So it looks like generateStage() is doing the check of whether more tiles need to be rendered. But I can't quite figure out what the TiledMapExRenderer's renderTileLayer() is doing. I may need to just sit down for an hour and figure this out.